# Graphql polling - how to use the result of previous request?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

In React application, I need to implement polling called every few seconds and I need to pass to the Graphql query the value which is the result of the previous query - one of the fields returned. I'm not sure how to pass it to the options. I tried a few attitudes like the below when I try to pass current component props to the query but it doesn't work:

```
@graphql(somequery, {
  options: ({ options, props }) => 
     ({ variables: { options, props }, fetchPolicy: 'network-only', pollInterval: 5000 }),
...
})
```

Is the polling good idea here? Or maybe I should use refetch or even something else?